# CMS Module agnostic with dependency injection (symfony, dependency-injection, container)

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, architecture, symfony-dependency-injection

*I'm trying to develop a library in PHP. This library will be used in modules for CMS (Wordpress, Drupal, PrestaShop for example).*

Each CMS has different specificities and very special ways of doing things: on PrestaShop, for example, we have access to the symfony dependency injection system.

On Wordpress, this system doesn't exist at all and the norm is to create a Singleton and make a big mess.

I'm looking for a simple architecture that I could use in my library because it's becoming complex and a dependency injection/container system would be very useful.

I've focused on PrestaShop because I can use Symfony DI directly in my library, but I've come across a problem: **I need to make database calls (something specific to each module) so I need a service that is defined in the PrestaShop container except that I can't find a "clean" way of retrieving this service in my module container.**.

In the library, the container is defined like that :

```
private function createContainer()
{
    $container = new ContainerBuilder();

    $configurationLoader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Ressources/config'));
    $configurationLoader->load('services.yml');

    $container->compile();

    return $container;
}
```

I found I could technically do this to fix my problem, **but it no longer works when I want to use PhpDumper and cache my library container:**

```
private function createContainer(WidgetRepositoryInterface $widgetRepository)
{
    $container = new ContainerBuilder();

    $container->set('repository.widget_repository', $widgetRepository);
    $container->setAlias(WidgetRepositoryInterface::class, 'repository.widget_repository');

    $configurationLoader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Ressources/config'));
    $configurationLoader->load('services.yml');

    $container->compile();

    return $container;
}
```

I think I'm in a bit of a loop where I don't really know how to merge the containers :

- I've tried extension systems.
- I looked at the compiler pass on my library.
- I tried importing the "service.yml" file for my library from the PrestaShop module files.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Adding service instances to the container is not going to work.  It's highly unlikely that something like a repository instance could be cached.  You need to add service definition statements to your createContainer method.  Or are you saying you intend to have two containers? If so then maybe a service locator might help.

Comment: That's right, in my current system I have a container for my library and there's the basic symfony container for the PrestaShop CMS. I'd like to be able to merge them so that I can decorate my services, which should be specific to each CMS.

Comment: You might try asking on [Symfony's Discussion board](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions). I don't think there is any general way to merge two containers and decorate services from one container in another.  I think you will need an extension for each CMS specific library and just have one container. Or maybe give up on the idea of caching.  But the discussion folks might have different ideas.